# regex string show me an error

Tags: javascript, regex

What is wrong with my regex

It is my first try to use regex. However I have a small problem.
When I run my regex in chrome console, it seems to work. However my Komodo Edit shows me an error (invalid range in character class) in the following line:

```js
s = s.replace(/([^0-9,-\s])/g,"");
```

I want to allow only those characters:

```
0-9
,
-
\s (whitespace)
```

for example input: `s1,2,3,4 ,5 / #, 7-9"` should give me: `1,2,3,4 ,5  , 7-9`

I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is used to select range of characters.

Move `-` to the end of `regex`.

```
/([^0-9,\s-])/
```

OR escape it using slash `\`

```
/([^0-9,\-\s])/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.replace(/([^0-9,\s-])/g,"");
```

Keep `-` at end or `escape` it.`-` inside character class forms a range(invalid in this case).