# Match empty string, comma, hyphen or underscore once using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, match

I'm trying to figure out how to match the following strings:

```
blaOSXbla
os X bla
bla os-x
blablaOS_Xbla
```

A common pattern is pretty easy: `/(osx|os x|os-x|os_x)/i.test(string)`

The task is to minimize it as much as possible. So my next step is 
`/(os)x| x|-x|_x)/i.test(string)`.

I've also tried `/os(.*?)x/` pattern, but it matches any number of symbols between `os` and `x`. How do I make it match **zero or one symbol**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/os[ _-]?x/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6bO9/1)

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.
>
> A character class matches only a single character. `gr[ae]y` does not match `graay`, `graey` or any such thing. The order of the characters inside a character class does not matter. The results are identical.

And you need `?` to make the match optional.

See ["Optional Items"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

> The question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional. `colou?r` matches both `colour` and `color`. The question mark is called a quantifier.

Comment: I believe `-` should be escaped

Comment: @ben Not when it is at the end

Comment: @ben: No, since it is at the end of a character class. This is called "smart placement" in some sources. It is supported by almost all regex engine flavors. Although, in ElasticSearch, the hyphen should be at the beginning of a character range in order not to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
/os[ \-_]?x)/i.test(string)
```

Use `?` to match the previous set zero or one time.

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com/3bd42)

Comment: Why do you use escaping character? It's out of the regexp function, so it can likely be omitted.

Comment: @Shaels In some browsers, it is treated as `range` selector, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284144/regex-string-show-me-an-error/31284156#31284156. So, it's good to have, rather than error

Comment: @Shaels: Hyphen inside a character class should be escaped if it is not at the starting and final positions, and when it can form a range. Note also, that if placed after a shorthand class, `-` will be treated as a literal, too (as in `[\d-_]`).