# match two exact characters in regex or (pipe) clause

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse shorthand notation into an integer representation. This works fine for Hours, Seconds, and Minutes, but not with Milliseconds, where the regex is failing to match.

`'50ms'.match(/^(\d+)([MS|S|M|H|ms|s|m|h])$/);`

I wasn't sure how to phrase the question correctly, but i did perform several searches prior to asking here.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxwaodyh/1/)

Comment: `[MS|S|M|H|ms|s|m|h]` -> `(MS|S|M|H|ms|s|m|h)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you post it as an answer i will accept it. all these different regex implementations are driving me freaking insane.

Comment: [`/H|(M?S?)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/uH1oS2/1)

Comment: I posted my answer with explanation why your regex does not work. The only regex flavor that uses `[...]` brackets for *grouping sequences* (not taking into consideration collations) is Perl6. Others always use `(...)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh really, no kidding? i was asking you to post it as an answer so that i could reward your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to match *sequences* of characters, you need to use [alternation groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) defiend with `(...|...)` constructs.

A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) only matches a single character defined in it. See more [details on character class here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31429267/3832970).

Your regex does not work with milliseconds because you require 1 character after digits followed with the end of string *immediately*. Thus, there is no place for 2 letters "ms".

So, the correct way is to use

```
'50ms'.match(/^(\d+)(MS|S|M|H|ms|s|m|h)$/);
```

As Tushar suggests, you can further contract the pattern using `/i` modifier and reducing the number of alternatives.

```
/^(\d+)(MS|ms|[SMH])$/i
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT1eP0/1)

Comment: `/H|(M?S?)/i` just matches more than the original regex. If `12Ms` or `14mS` should be matched, the `/^(\d+)(H|M?S?)$/i` can be used.

Comment: I guess that since you didn't include it in answer :)